# Testing launching activity intents with espresso

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-testing

I would like to make a simple UI test, where a button being pressed and an activity being launched.

I have tried based on [this documentation.](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing/espresso-testing.html) (android developers)

### Code of SplashActivity:

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    findViewById(R.id.launch_register_activity_btn).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
}
```

### Testing Code:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class SimpleIntentTest {

@Rule
public IntentsTestRule<SplashActivity> intentsRule = new IntentsTestRule<>(SplashActivity.class);

@Test
public void newActivityLaunchingTest() {


    onView(withId(R.id.launch_register_activity_btn)).perform(click());

    Log.i("register-package_name", RegisterActivity.class.getPackage().toString());
    Log.i("register-class_name", RegisterActivity.class.getName());
    Log.i("register-short_name", RegisterActivity.class.getSimpleName());


    intended(allOf(
            hasComponent(hasShortClassName(".RegisterActivity")),
            toPackage("re.example.common")
    ));


}
}
```

### Logcat:

```
01-22 13:37:51.615: I/register-package_name(25292): package re.example.common, Unknown, version 0.0
01-22 13:37:51.615: I/register-class_name(25292): re.example.common.RegisterActivity
01-22 13:37:51.615: I/register-short_name(25292): RegisterActivity
```

### Package structure:

[image]

### Test output:

```
android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler$AssertionFailedWithCauseError: Wanted to match 1 intents. Actually matched 0 intents.

IntentMatcher: (has component: has component with: class name: an instance of java.lang.String package name: an instance of java.lang.String short class name: is ".RegisterActivity" and resolvesTo: re.example.common)

Matched intents:[]
```

No matter how I try, **the test does not validate that I had launched RegisterActivity**. The test fails.

As far as I know I did exactly like in the espresso-testing example at the link above.

What am I doing wrong?

### I have also tried:

**1. Removing the . (dot) from ".RegisterActivity"**

```
intended(allOf(
            hasComponent(hasShortClassName("RegisterActivity")),
            toPackage("re.example.common")
    ));
```

**2. Removing the . (dot) from ".RegisterActivity"** and   **toPackage("re.example.common")**

```
intended(allOf(
            hasComponent(hasShortClassName("RegisterActivity"))
    ));
```

My RegisterActivity's package name is **"re.example.common.RegisterActivity"**.
The **short** name is **"RegisterActivity"**. Isn't it?

Why the test fails?

### What's happening here, what am I misunderstand or misconcept?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The fact that this  `Matched intents:[]` happens, indicates that espresso didn't record any intents at all. Have you tried putting a bit of a delay to rule out the ui-thread synchronization, just to test the theory?

And a silly question - does the button actually work if tested manually? And the last question what Os are you running you tests against?

Comment: @Be_Negative Putting delay should not be necessary. One of espresso's core feature is that you don't have to put delay anywhere. (I have disabled all animations as the docs suggests) I have tested it manually and it works, I'm testing against my real device, Xiaomi Mi A1, Android 8.0

Comment: You don't have a Recorded Intents part in the test output(can you attach that part to your question?) Did you tried to match individually on those matchers?  Also make sure you're not changing the actual package name of the app in the build file by using a prefix, suffix etc.

Comment: @AdamVarhegyi  That is why I said "just to test the theory".  Ok, last one from me   - can you try running the same code on api below 26? there is an open issue https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37084501 against api 26, i haven't run intentstestrule on anything higher because of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Application id** (app package name is) **is:** `re.example` (source gradle)

The activity's **full name** is: `re.example.common.RegisterActivity`

This way, `hasShortClassName` meant to be `.common.RegisterActivity` as **shortName** and not `.RegisterActivity` nor `RegisterActivity`

### Meh.

---